# Is java Web Start Application using my browser each time I run the application?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I would like to know if when I launch my `Java Web Start` application, I'm using my browser or the connection is directly from the `Java` sandbox against the server through `Http`/`Https` protocol.

I want ot know, wether once the `JAR` has been downloaded and stored locally, next time when the applciation is launched, it will use my browser?

Answer (score 4):

No, Java WebStart doesn't use the browser. It uses the JRE to connect to a remote server using HTTP or HTTPS.

The browser is only involved in the download of the .jnlp file. And even here, you could send the JNLP file by e-mail or any other mean. It would work too.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Also an interesting fast link [Applet vs JAWS](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javawebstart.html#APPLETSVSJWS)

Comment: Hm, interesting idea that - to provide the JNLP through different means than the web. Never really considered the possibility. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I'm developing a JWS application where the JNLP file is copied on the workstations by an external company responsible for the workstations (they install software).

Comment: You can also call `javaws abc.jnlp` directly from the command line.